# Run a command when elFinder loaded

Tags: elfinder

I want to open "Upload files" dialog automatically when elFinder loaded.
I found this function was run after elFinder loaded, but I can't bind or call upload command.

```
$('selector').elfinder({
    // options ...
    handlers : {
        load : function(event, elfinder) {
            console.log(elfinder);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, there isn't documentation about this, so after some messing around this was my solution.

First you need to get the instance of elfinder:

```
elf1 = $('#fexplorer').elfinder({...options...});
elf=elf1.elfinder('instance');
```

When you have it you can call any command this way:

```
elf.exec('upload');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should ask for the command and the execute it!.
it works for elFinder (2.1.46)

```
var _elFinder = $("#finder").elfinder(
   {url : '/processAdmin/connector/' + idProceso,
    lang: 'es',
    width:'auto',
    height:200,
    commands: ['rename','upload'],
    ui:[],
    disabled:['extract', 'archive', 'mkdir'],
    sortStickFolders:true,
    resizable:false,
    customData : {'numDocumento':numDocument}
    },
    function(fm, extraObj) {
       // `init` event callback function
       setTimeout(function() {
       elf = _elFinder.elfinder('instance');
       cmd = elf._commands['upload'];
       cmd.exec();
       }, 500);}
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Execute the upload command after executing the first open command.

```
$('selector').elfinder({
    // options ...
    handlers : {
        load : function(event, elfinder) {
            elfinder.one('open', function() {
                elfinder.exec('upload');
            });
        }
    }
});
```